# How can I properly configure outline-client?

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, vpn

I want to create a `VPN` using outline client for windows, but my routing configuration is not working.

```bash
.\tun2socks.exe -tunName outline-tap0 -tunDNS 1.1.1.1,9.9.9.9 -tunAddr 10.0.85.2 -tunGw 10.0.85.1 -tunMask 255.255.255.0  -proxyHost 195.225.22.48  -proxyPort 2222 -proxyPassword riaz123  -proxyCipher aes-128-gcm
```

**Note: it's enable the `outline-tap0 interface` but not pass `data throw the interface`**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try replace the placeholders (proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyPassword, and other parameters) with your actual configuration details. Ensure that the Outline client is configured correctly and that the outline-tap0 network interface is operational.

```bash
.\tun2socks.exe -tunName outline-tap0 -tunDNS 1.1.1.1,9.9.9.9 -tunAddr 10.0.85.2 -tunGw 10.0.85.1 -tunMask 255.255.255.0 -proxyHost 195.225.22.48 -proxyPort 2222 -proxyPassword riaz123 -proxyCipher aes-128-gcm
```

If data is not passing through the interface as expected, just check the configuration details is correct, especially the proxy settings and network interface configuration, and consult the tun2socks and Outline client documentation for specific requirements or troubleshooting steps related to your version of the software.

Comment: "and consult the tun2socks and Outline client documentation" We don't write like that here.